# Partial derivate equation

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $ w = f(x-y,y-z,z-x)$. Show that $ \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} = 0$

I wouldn't have problem, if it was written in $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^3 + z^4$ or something similar. Can I ask for little help what to start with?

Thank you!

Comment: Is a composite function. Use the chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show you how to compute the first partial derivative; you can do the others to finish the problem. As Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla said, use the multivariable chain rule:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-y) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(y-z) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(z-x) \\
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! It's a pity, but hint wasn't enough.

Comment: No problem! The multivariable chain rule can be tricky to apply.